# How to pass an array of vectors to a function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have defined an array of vectors, and want to pass this array to a function.

Here's my code:

```
void gridlist(std::vector<int> *grid, int rows, int cols){
    ..... }

int rows=4;
int cols=5;
std::vector<int> grid[rows][cols];

gridlist(grid,rows,cols);
```

The only method which has worked for me to pass arrays to a function was by pointer (*) ?.

I've tried different method according to following descriptions: [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function), but I didn't manage to get it working.

I always get the following error:

```
could not convert '(std::vector<int> (*)[cols])(& grid)' from 'std::vector<int> (*)[cols]' to 'std::vector<int>'
       gridlist(grid,rows, cols);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. What is, in general, considered the best/safest method to do that task?

Comment: Using vector of vectors or `std::array` of vectors seems good.

Comment: Have you tried, as a good two-star programmer would do, using std::vector<int> **grid , or do you want the array sizes passed as type parameters?

Comment: Why don't you just pass a vector of vectors?

Comment: @lorro, That won't work; a 2D arrays decays into a pointer to a 1D array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @lorro, please explain yourself. Who is good 2-star programmer?

Comment: "I have defined an array of vectors" - no, you defined an array of arrays of `std::vector<int>`, and non-standard at that (constant `rows` and `cols` can address the latter).

Comment: Thank you everybody for all those different solutions, I decided to go with a 3D vector, as i still couldnt pass the array to the function without getting any errors. The code is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a template:

```
template<int rows, int cols>
void gridlist(std::vector<int> (&grid)[rows][cols]){

}

int main()
{
const int rows=4;
const int cols=5;
std::vector<int> grid[rows][cols];

gridlist(grid);
}
```

there is additional change in your code, `int rows=4;` to `const int rows=4;` this is because VLA (variable length arrays) are non standard in C++. If you want dynamic array then consider using vector of vectors of vectors (whhooh) instead: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
void gridlist(std::vector<int> *grid, int rows, int cols){
    ..... }

int rows=4;
int cols=5;
std::vector<int> grid[rows][cols];

gridlist(grid,rows,cols);
```

Here `grind` has the type `std::vector<int>[][]`, while `grindlist()` expects `std::vector<int> *`. You'd have to either have to make `grindlist()` expect `std::vector<int>[] *`, or make sure `grind` is a `std::vector<int>[]`

I'd propose to prefer `std::array<>` instead:

```
template<int rows, int cols>
void gridlist(std::array<std::array<std::vector<int>, cols>, rows>& grid) {
    ..... }

constexpr int rows = 4;
constexpr int cols = 5;
std::array<std::array<std::vector<int>, cols>, rows> grid;

gridlist(grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the 2D array directly if you want variable size of both dimensions.

One solution is to fix the size of `cols` and declare your function like:

```
void gridlist1(std::vector<int> grid[][5],int rows){...}
```

If it isn't acceptable to fix the size of one dimension, you can use a temp variable instead:

```
void gridlist(std::vector<int> **grid,int rows, int cols){...}
```

and call it like:

```
const int rows=4;
const int cols=5;

std::vector<int> grid[rows][cols]; 

// Temp variable
std::vector<int>* temp[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) temp[i] = grid[i];

gridlist(temp,rows,cols);
         ^^^^
```

However, I would use vector of vector of vector instead of a traditional c-style array.

Comment: Thats what i actually did to continue working, but i needed the variable size, thanks for the workaround with the temp variable!